# Is there a way to pass type arguments in message variable in protobuf file?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, protocol-buffers, grpc

Is there a way to pass type arguments in response message of protobuf file?

For example, I have a response type of `SResponse<E>` with uses generic argument and I want to do same in my protobuf file.

I have tried searching on web nothing specific is mentioned in docs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Different values of `E` must be represented by different protobuf messages.

You will want to:

- Either cast your generic types to a single protobuf message
- Or define a protobuf message per value of `E`

Comment: You could use `Any`, if you really wanted, but you wouldn't get type safety.